# Timing issue on schema validation with JSchema

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I want to validate json objects in a JArray with a schema. My test array contains >100000 Objects. During timing analysis i found out that it takes many times (>500x) longer to validate the last object compared to the first object in the Array.

Here a part of my test code:

```
      ...
      string schemaShapeObjectStr = @"{ 'type':'object',
                              '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema',
                              'required':false, 
                                  'properties':{ 
                                      'MyShapeObject': { 
                                          'type':'object', 'id': 'MyShapeObject', 'required':true, 
                                          'properties':{ 
                                              'id': {'type':'string', 'id': 'id', 'maxLength': 6,'required':true},
                                              'XY': {'type': 'array','minItems': 2,'maxItems': 2,'uniqueItems': false,'required':true,
                                                  'items': {'type': 'number','multipleOf': 0.001,'minimum': -10000,'maximum': 10000},
                                                  'additionalItems': false
                                              }
                                          }, 'additionalProperties':false 
                                      } 
                                  } 
                              }";
      ...

      JSchema schemaMoveOverTo = JSchema.Parse(schemaMoveOverToStr);

      JArray shapeArray = (JArray)shapes["shape"];

      Int32 counter = 0;

      JObject itemFast = (JObject)shapeArray.First();
      JObject itemSlow = (JObject)shapeArray.Last();

      sw1.Reset();
      sw1.Start();

      foreach (JObject item in shapeArray.Children<JObject>())
      {
          if (item.Properties().First().Name == "MyShapeObject")
          {
              counter++;
              stopwatch2.Reset();
              stopwatch2.Start();
              valid = itemFast.IsValid(schemaShapeObject, out messages);
              stopwatch2.Stop();
              calcTimeFast += stopwatch2.Elapsed;

              stopwatch2.Reset();
              stopwatch2.Start();
              valid = itemSlow.IsValid(schemaShapeObject, out messages);
              stopwatch2.Stop();
              calcTimeSlow += stopwatch2.Elapsed;
          }
      }
      sw1.Stop();
      meassureString = string.Format("loopThru Time = {0}, ShapeObject = {1}", sw1.Elapsed, counter);
      OutPutWindow.AppendText(meassureString + Environment.NewLine);
      meassureString = string.Format("Fast Time = {0}, Fast Mean = {1}, Slow Time = {2}, Slow Mean = {3}", calcTimeFast.TotalMilliseconds, (calcTimeFast.TotalMilliseconds / counter), calcTimeSlow.TotalMilliseconds, (calcTimeSlow.TotalMilliseconds / counter));
      OutPutWindow.AppendText(meassureString + Environment.NewLine);
    ...
```

i got this Output:

```
loopThru Time = 00:06:36.1059322, ShapeObject = 89857
Fast Time = 628.6673, Fast Mean = 0.0069963085, Slow Time = 394959.2331, Slow Mean = 4.3954197569
```

For my test the first and the last object are equal!

In an other test i found out, that the schema validating time increases continuous with the position in the array...

Can anyone explain me this strange behavior. To be honest i'm a C++ developer and new in C#. In my opinion the two JObject's (itemFast, itemSlow) are equal and independed where they come from!?

Is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you looping over the result from `shapeArray.Children<JObject>()` and then never using it?

Are itemFast and itemSlow the same JSON? That might explain the difference. If not then upload a console project with a repo somewhere I'll take a look at it.

Comment: It is just a test. When i use every JObject from array, the measured time increases from first to last. So i changed it to find out if it increases by count or by the position in the array. And the answer seem that it depends on position in the array. Here is a [Link](http://stvkriessern.owncube.com/index.php/s/42lsLb5ut6qbP9g) to a console project.

Comment: JObject itemSlow = (JObject)shapeArray.Last().DeepClone(); // Temporary work around. This fixes the performance issue. Not sure why yet.

Comment: Ok, I found a performance issue related to validating an item in a JSON array with many items, and that is causing your issue. Calling DeepClone on a JObject before you validate it solves the issue. There will be a fix in the library but it won't be released for about a month.